# EF Code First 4.3.1 Migrations: Always seeding data even though nothing changed

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-4, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I'm using the new migrations in my ASP.NET MVC 4 project and within the Migrations/Configuration file I have the following:

```
public Configuration()
        {
            AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
            AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = false;
        }
```

In the same file file, I also have a Seed method that populates my database. I've noticed that every time I run my app, it reseeds the database even though the model hasn't changed. Within my global.asax file I have the following Database Initializer in Application_Start

```
Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<UtilitiesContext, Migrations.Configuration>());
```

I only want it to seed the database if the model changes or I run the Update-Database command. How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I just removed the initializer statement all together and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

What about DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges? See this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679604%28v=vs.103%29.aspx).  This will only reseed if the database is different than the model.

Usage:

```
 Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<UtilitiesContext>());
```